# How to debug static lib within the project while development?

Tags: swift

I have my static lib code which I use in another app, so after I add the lib into the app there is no way to debug the lib source as the app doesn't know about the lib source nothing.

My question is there a way kind of to add a path to the source just for debug reasons, so the source won't be included in the build?

Comment: IMO add enough logging (using `os_log`) to the static lib. You will still be able to see it in the app. Another option is for static lib to have some hooks which would allow your app to plug to and retrieve internal info. It's a bit hackish, but it can work for internal libraries you are not planning to share. An uglier option is to have a special debug target that compiles static lib and your app as one code base...

Comment: @ohglstr I am not sure if I explained myself clear, actually what I need is somehow to be able debug the static lib code, however in the app itself only `.a` file is included, not a source itself (but source of the lib is my code also), so I need somehow (only for debug reasons) be able to debug that lib sources (but they should not be included in the app itself, only `.a` file)

Comment: I don't think the full debugging is possible. If you have your `GENERATE_DEBUG_SYMBOLS` set to true, you might be able to add a symbolic breakpoint for static library methods (I think), but that's about it.

Comment: @ohglstr so looks like the only normal solution is to create a kind of demo project where I can add my lib and there simulate all the possible behavior, then all the lib as `.a` file to the main project

Comment: pretty much... or a special target, that includes the sources from static lib and compiles them together with the app

Comment: @ohglstr actually add a target could be a solution as only those devs who has the source on their machines can switch to the specific target and debug lib code and those who don't have a source can't work with lib debug, but still can launch the app as they have `.a` file, am I missing something?

Comment: In one of my projects we had it like that: 1 workspace, 2 projects: static library and app. The app includes static library as such (.a) but since they ar ein the same workspace, we could debug classes within static library when building the app.

Comment: So, finally, I created the workspace and put there 2 projects: lib and another one is app project. As a workspace kind of set of specific user setting it should not be pushed in the repo thus those who have such a workspace and a lib source use it, and those who don't - don't. Pretty easy working solution